# Multiple data in Excel Graphs

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013, charts

I'm trying to create a graph using the following data with time on the horizontal axis and sale price on the vertical. I envisage assigning a different color to each bedroom size rather than creating a separate axis. Can anybody suggest the best way to do this?

```
**# of bedrooms    Sale Price       Date**
1                   $100,000      October 15
1                   $115,000      November 15
2                   $150,000      January 16
2                   $158,000      January 16
2                   $160,000      January 16
3                   $190,000      Active (currently listed)
```

Comment: what about the same type of bedrooms at the same date? do you want to list them separately / calculate sum / average??

Comment: I want to list them separately in order to be able to see all of the data points rather than an average

Comment: You're trying to show trend over time for each level of bedrooms.  The logical approach would be to make each number of bedrooms a separate series and plot them all against date on a scatter (XY) chart.  Points, only, will differentiate with color, but points plus lines will also make the trends more visible.  Put Date in the leftmost column, then use a separate column for each # Bedrooms, which will contain the Sale Price data.  You will probably need to format the X axis as a date so it doesn't display as the internally stored value.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the bubble chart since it can take 3 values. The size of the bubble would denote the number of bedrooms.